# What does the "i" mean in input[type="color" i] { ....?

Tags: css

It's a user agent style:

[image]

What is the meaning of `i` in this `input[type="color" i]`

Comment: [Read the docs?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Please share more details, like code to reproduce the problem. As this might be happening only in special constellations: is it relevant which browser you are using, on which OS? Or could you reproduce it in multiple different browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

> [attr operator value i]
>
> Adding an i (or I) before the closing bracket causes the value to be compared case-insensitively (for characters within the ASCII range).

That means that the word `color` can be lower-, upper- or mixed case and the rule will still match.